# Is it possible to get active sessions per hour in SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-analysis

| start_time | end_time | HostID | gameID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6/14/2021 20:13 | 6/14/2021 22:22 | 1 | AB1 |
| 6/14/2021 20:20 | 6/14/2021 21:47 | 2 | AB2 |
| 6/14/2021 20:22 | 6/14/2021 22:07 | 3 | AB3 |
| 6/14/2021 20:59 | 6/14/2021 21:15 | 4 | AB4 |
| 6/15/2021 21:24 | 6/15/2021 22:09 | 1 | AB5 |
| 6/15/2021 21:24 | 6/15/2021 21:59 | 2 | AB6 |
| 6/15/2021 23:11 | 6/16/2021 01:22 | 4 | AB7 |
| 6/16/2021 20:13 | 6/16/2021 21:23 | 3 | AB8 |

I have a table that has a start time and end time. I want to count the active game rooms per hour. I know I should have at least try solving this but I really don't know where to start or if is this even possible with SQL.

What I first did is to COUNT how many gameID there are in an hour using the start_time. But I'm sure I did not answer the 'active' per session question. What I did was to just COUNT how many has started a game per hour.

The expected result is something like this

DayHour

| Time | Active |
| --- | --- |
| 6/14/2021 2000 | 4 |
| 6/15/2021 2100 | 4 |
| 6/16/2021 2200 | 2 |
| 6/15/2021 2100 | 2 |
| 6/16/2021 2200 | 1 |
| 6/17/2021 2300 | 1 |
| 6/16/2021 0 | 1 |
| 6/17/2021 1 | 1 |
| 6/18/2021 2000 | 1 |
| 6/19/2021 2100 | 1 |

Or count of active sessions per hour without grouping by day.

Hr

| Time | Active |
| --- | --- |
| 2000 | 5 |
| 2100 | 7 |
| 2200 | 3 |
| 2300 | 1 |
| 0000 | 1 |
| 0001 | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest below solution

```
select timestamp_trunc(minute, hour) hour, 
  count(distinct hostid) hosts,
  count(distinct gameid) games
from `project.dataset.table`, 
unnest(generate_timestamp_array(
  parse_timestamp('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M', start_time), 
  parse_timestamp('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M', end_time), 
  interval 1 minute)) minute
group by hour
# order by hour
```

if applied to sample data in your question (with fix for end_time in last row - should be 6/16/2021 21:23 - not 6/6/2021 21:23) - output is

[image]

Brief explanation

1. Expand/split each original row into one row for each minute between `start_time` and `end_time`
2. And then, simply aggregate by `hour` applying `count(distinct ...)`

> Or count of active sessions per hour without grouping by day.

You can apply exactly same approach

```
select extract(hour from minute) hour, 
  count(distinct hostid) hosts,
  count(distinct gameid) games
from `project.dataset.table`, 
unnest(generate_timestamp_array(
  parse_timestamp('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M', start_time), 
  parse_timestamp('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M', end_time), 
  interval 1 minute)) minute
group by hour
order by hour
```

with output

[image]

Comment: so, have you tried it? does above work for you?!

Comment: Given the snaps you included, it should but I'm still trying to figure out how to use parse_timestamp to datatime expressions with this format: 2021-10-11T16:06:43.  Also, why are we doing it in a per minute interval instead of a per hour intervals? Are we performing a cross join in the FROM statement? Is that what's happening?

Comment: what worked is the timestamp() function. thanks,

Answer (score 1):

A simple method is to unpivot the data and then aggregate.  To get the numbers at any time in the data:

```
with se as (
      select start_time as time, 1 as inc from t
      union all
      select end_time, -1 as inc from t
     )
select time, sum(sum(inc)) over (order by time) as actives
from se
group by time;
```

Then, you need to define what you mean by "per hour".  You can get the first result in each hour using `trunc()`:

```
with se as (
      select start_time as time, 1 as inc from t
      union all
      select end_time, -1 as inc from t
     )
select time, sum(sum(inc)) over (order by time) as actives
from se
group by time
qualify row_number() over (partition by date_trunc(time, hour) order by time) = 1;
```